# How to use gRPC in WebExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket, protocol-buffers, firefox-addon-webextensions

A WebExtension I am creating has to make gRPC calls to a server over a websocket connection. I have problems figuring out how to set up gRPC and protocol buffers so that I can generate stubs that I can use in my WebExtension.

I tried google's compiler, but it outputs code that uses eval / manually constructed functions.
Since WebExtensions have a restricted subset of javascript, I was thinking that protobuf.js might help, as it can generate code that does not use eval, but I was unable to get it to work.
I have been trying to wrap my head around this for the past few days already, but this specific case is hard to figure out from the available documentation alone.

Can someone give me a step by step guide on how to set up the tools necessary, generate WebExtension-compatible code, and finally, use it with a websocket connection?

Comment: You can use evals in extensions either by [modifying CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) or in a [sandboxed iframe](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval).

Comment: Is there a way to keep the CSP as is? I am working with sensitive data in my WebExtension, and do not wish to reduce security.

Comment: Use the second approach I've mentioned.

Comment: This seems to not be portable to Firefox.

Comment: You can add `nonce` to CSP and use the nonce attribute to load those generated scripts. Another approach to try would be WASM.